# filling django forms based on choice with models data as initial data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Need help regarding adding `model class` fields as initial data to our `forms` data.

**models.py**

```
class SourceCode(models.Model):
    source_description = models.CharField(max_length=80,unique=True)
    source_urls = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True),),blank=True,null=True)
    source_results = JSONField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.source_description
```

**forms.py**

```
class SourceForm(forms.Form):
    source_description = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=SourceCode.objects.all(),required=True)
    source_form_urls = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter URLS Here'}))
```

> I had created `Source1` object & added `https://stackoverflow.com` value in `source_urls` field.

[image]

---

*Here's how it looks like:*

> As soon as i select `Source1` from `forms.ModelChoiceField`, i want it to show the `source_urls` field data of `source_urls` based on object selected by user.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a JavaScript solution is needed.

You could either load all source_urls in the template after setting a context variable called 'source_urls' in your views context:

Your view:

```
class YourViewName():

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['source_urls'] = SourceCode.objects.values('id', 'source_urls')
        return context_data
```

In template:

```
<script>
    var source_urls = {
        {% for su in source_urls %}
        "{{ su.id }}": "{{ su.source_urls }}",
        {% endfor %}
    }
</script>
```

Then add something to your JavaScript:

```
$('#source_description_id').change(function() {
    $('#source_form_urls_id').val(source_urls[$(this).val()]);
});
```

---

Or you could create another view that searches for the source_urls with an ajax call:

```
def source_url_searcher(request):

    source_id = request.GET.get('id')
    source_urls = SourceCode.objects.get(id=source_id).source_urls 

    return return JsonResponse({source_urls: source_urls})
```

And your JavaScript:

```
$('#source_description_id').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: <the_ajax_url>,
        data: {source_id: $(this).val()},
        success: function(response) {
            $('#source_form_urls_id').val(response.source_urls);
        }
    });
});
```

---

Either example would need some polishing to work correctly, but they provide the general idea.

Comment: using ajax is nice trick,Will learn about `first` method context, Hence marking solution as resolved. Thanks for writing it :)